# Python AST - merging two ASTs

Tags: python, merge, abstract-syntax-tree, python-ast

Do you have any idea how can i merge two asts using python ast?
I would like to do something like this:

```
n1 = ast.parse(input_a)
n2 = ast.parse(input_b)
n = merge(n1,n2)
```

I would like create root n with childs n1 and n2.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you need to specify the type of nodes that you have?  it seems like this would be highly dependent on `input_a` and `input_b`.

Comment: for example, both inputs can be definition of function and i need to merge this two asts into one. I dont want to call ast parser on both together, because if one of them is non valid, i dont get any output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you can do this:

```
n1.body += n2.body
```

But I can't find that documented anywhere.

Sample:

```
>>> a=ast.parse("i=1")
>>> b=ast.parse("j=2")
>>> a.body += b.body
>>> exec compile(a, "<string>", "exec")
>>> print i
1
>>> print j
2
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, am unable to find the method ( body() ). I am creating translation unit using index.parse('my_Input_file') what is the ast in the solution?